# Cannot GET route express/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning more about APIs so I decided to build a simple API for beer/breweries and it was working great then suddenly no routes would work. I tested it by creating a new route that is purely for testing this issue and it works fine. So, I simplified my other routes to literally just send a message back to the DOM with a `res.send()` to see if cutting the DB connection out would help me pinpoint the problem.

This test route works as intended by sending a message to the DOM of "hello!" (`/app/routes/test_routes.js`):

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello!");
  });
};
```

However, this does not work at all despite being identical in function (`/app/routes/brewery_routes.js`):

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.get('/brewery', (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello!");
  });
};
```

This is the routes index that pulls all my routes in (`/app/routes/index.js`):

```
const beerRoutes = require('./beer_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  beerRoutes(app, db);
};

const breweryRoutes = require('./brewery_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  breweryRoutes(app, db);
};

const cityRoutes = require('./city_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  cityRoutes(app, db);
};

const testRoutes = require('./test_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  testRoutes(app, db);
};
```

This is my server file that handles all of the routes (`/server.js`):

```
const express     = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
const app         = express();
const db          = require('./config/db');

const PORT = 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

MongoClient.connect(db.url,(err, database) =>{

  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }

  require('./app/routes')(app, database);

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("We are pouring beer at port " + PORT);
  });
});
```

My app's general file structure is:

```
Root/ 
  app/
    routes/
      index.js
      test_routes.js
      brewery_routes.js
      beer_routes.js
      city_routes.js
  server.js
```

What's weird is when I view the console logs I see no errors for my `/test` route but the other routes come back with this huge list of font errors. As you can see by my code I don't have any fonts loaded so I am wondering if this is a bigger issue than I am aware of.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: this is something that's being loaded by your client libraries. Something in a CSS file or other place that you've not shown here.

Comment: @Paul aside from my package.json file that was produced by my npm init I have nothing else in my project that I didn't show. This is purely for an API and no frontend as part of it. The selected answer from jfriend resolved that font error. My issue was putting multiple module.exports in one file instead of all of my route functions inside a single module.exports. Thanks for the try though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `index.js`, you assign multiple things to `module.exports` over and over.  Only the last one will survive and be available to whoever  requires the module.  You don't show the code that loads index.js and attempts to use those routes so I have no idea what the proper solution is, but this sure explains why only the last route `/app/routes/test_routes.js`in index.js could ever work.

So, each of these assignments to `module.exports`, overwrites the previous one.  Only the last one survives and is actually exported:

```
const beerRoutes = require('./beer_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  beerRoutes(app, db);
};

const breweryRoutes = require('./brewery_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  breweryRoutes(app, db);
};

const cityRoutes = require('./city_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  cityRoutes(app, db);
};

const testRoutes = require('./test_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  testRoutes(app, db);
};
```

This is just like:

```
let a;

a = function() { console.log("1"); }
a = function() { console.log("2"); }

a();    // outputs "2"
```

---

It may be that this is what you want:

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
    require('./beer_routes')(app, db);
    require('./brewery_routes')(app, db);
    require('./city_routes')(app, db);
    require('./test_routes')(app, db);
}
```

Then, when the module is loaded and the constructor is called, you will initailize all these routes.

Comment: The index.js file from the routes directory gets imported into the server.js file toward the bottom via the require app/routes but honestly you got it with your first point. It was the multiple module.exports I had in the index.js file. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you so much for your help.